# I'd like to swap the speaker on an electronics kit for a reed relay

Tags: relay, speakers

Morning all, I've built the Velleman IR Light Barrier kit:
http://www.vellemanusa.com/us/enu/product/view/?id=350693

It currently beeps when the light barrier is broken, but I'd like to remove the speaker and replace it with a reed relay to trigger another circuit. I imagine I'll also need to add some resistors in order to stop it from blowing the rest of the board, but am unsure how to work out what to add.

I've got a reasonable multi-meter, which can measure DC & AC current/voltage, resistance and capacitance. If I can measure what I need to using it, could you please describe how - I'm not sure whether I should be bridging the contacts on the speaker, or introducing the meter into the circuit in series...

Please let me know if any of the above makes no sense, I usually keep these projects inside my head, and don't know how many of the terms I've used are correct and how many I've made up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks straight-forward. From the receiver schematic, the "speaker" is in fact a piezo sounder and is DC driven so you can wire a relay coil in it's place. You will need to add a small general purpose diode (1N4148 or 1N914 etc) across the relay coil with the cathode connected to +V and the anode connected to the "speaker" output (T2 collector). You will need a small 9V relay with a coil resistance of at least 500 Ohms.

*EDIT:- I've attached a (badly drawn) sketch ...*

[image: Relay replacing sounder]

Comment: Does this mean that the circuit is currently sending a waveform to the speaker? Would a capacitor be used to smooth this out and keep my reed switch closed? how would I work out the required capacitance?

Comment: No. The circuit applies 9V dc to the sounder. The sounder has it's own built-in oscillator. The 9V output could equally be applied to a relay coil. The diode is required to suppress the voltage spike produced by the relay when it switches off - but some relays have this built-in.

Comment: Thanks for your help, found everything I need - just need to solder it with a minimum of burnt fingers